# Facebook app review - will adding permissions to existing app trigger review?

Tags: facebook, permissions

I built a prototype Facebook app (web app), which I believe was registered shortly before April 30, 2014. If I now want to change the permissions and rewrite the app, will I be subject to the new rules for approval? Does anyone know for sure?

Comment: If it was created before 4/30/2014 you will need to get all permissions approved before 4/30/2015

Comment: To be clear, does that mean I'll need them to sign off on changes I make right now?  Or just that at some point before 4/30/2015, I'll have to seek approval for everything?

Comment: You just need to do it before 4/30/2015

Comment: Just following up--the only way I see to change permissions right now involves pressing the button to submit for review.  Is there another way?

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you want a different way? Isn't that good enough?

Comment: Sorry, I probably haven't been clear.  I'm trying to change the permissions, run the app for a while, and only then submit for review--I'd prefer to do review in a few months' time rather than right now.

Comment: If the app was created before 4/30/2014 you can ask for any permission

Comment: I see--so they're granted automatically, because of when the app was created.

Comment: They are not approved. But you will be able to ask users for them until 4/30/2015. At 4/30/2015 you will not be able to ask for them if you haven't gotten them approved by then